# Set function not working on Customer\Visitor model for custom column

Tags: model, custom-column-grid, magento2.4.5

I am trying to add new custom columns for `now online customer grid`.

I have added new custom columns in `customer_visitor` table, but I am not able to save data in custom columns.

Firstly, I have added new custom columns in `customer_visitor` table with `db_schema.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="customer_visitor" resource="default">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="device_type" length="20" nullable="true" comment="Device Type"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="last_visited_page" length="255" nullable="true" comment="Last Visited Page (End Point URL)"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="last_visited_product" length="255" nullable="true" comment="Last Visited Product SKU"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**But when I tried to add value to these columns with 'set() function' then the value of default column is saved, but the value of custom column is not getting saved. Showing `NULL`**

Below I have shown with code and image, please check:

```
public function __construct(
   \Magento\Customer\Model\VisitorFactory $visitor,
   \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor $resourceModel
) {
   $this->visitor = $visitor;
   $this->resourceModel = $resourceModel;
}

public function createVisitor() {
   $visitorModel = $this->visitor->create();
   $this->resourceModel->
   load($visitorModel,'','visitor_id');
   $visitorModel->setCustomerId(0);
   $visitorModel->setCreatedAt("2022-09-16 12:10:39");
   $visitorModel->setLastVisitAt("2022-09-16 12:10:39");
   $visitorModel->setDeviceType("device type");
   $visitorModel->setLastVisitedPage("last page");
   $visitorModel->setLastVisitedProduct("product");
   $this->resourceModel->save($visitorModel);
        
   return $visitorModel;
}
```

[image]
[image]

I think this is a correct way, but it is not working. I don't know where I am wrong.
I am using `Magento2.4.5`.

What can I do to add value in custom column?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

When saving the data in a table in Magento way you should use the model and resource model for this, below is the following class for the resource model -

Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor

Now below is the sample code for saving data in a table using the model and resource model.

The main thing is you can create a factory for the model and set the data using setters(set()) and getters(get()) and load them up in the resourceModel using the load() function but you have to pass 3 arguments ->

1. modelFactory instance
2. primary key value (If this is auto increment then just give like this = '')
3. pass the primary column name.

**Sample code**

```
public function __construct(
   \Magento\Customer\Model\VisitorFactory $visitor,
   \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor $resourceModel
) {
   $this->visitor = $visitor;
   $this->resourceModel = $resourceModel;
}

public function createVisitor() {
   $visitorModel = $this->visitor->create();
   $this->resourceModel- 
   >load($visitorModel,'','primary_key_column_name');
   $visitorModel->setCustomerId(0);
   $visitorModel->setCreatedAt("2022-09-16 12:10:39");
   $visitorModel->setLastVisitAt("2022-09-16 12:10:39");
   $visitorModel->setDeviceType("device type");
   $visitorModel->setLastVisitedPage("last page");
   $visitorModel->setLastVisitedProduct("product");
   $this->resourceModel->save($visitorModel);
        
   return $visitorModel;
}
```

Hope this posts helps , you can always comment back if any more help is needed , please do give a like if this helped.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned, but it's not working.
I have updated Question, please check.

Comment: Hi @MukeshKhatri Do you get any errors because of this , can you try using try catch statements and share the error here ?